# Mac Photos: Change Date of selected photos

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, photos

I'm searching for a way to change the date of multiple photo in the Photos App on macOS.

Comment: The problem was that my camera said my photos from yesterday were from the year 2015. I fixed it on the camera now, but on Photos they're from 2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Photos app does not have a feature for changing the date of multiple photos to one particular date. You can, however, change multiple photos relative to their original date.

Select the desired photos by either holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking to select multiple adjacent photos, or holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking individual photos.

In the menu bar, go to Image -> Adjust Date and Time

You can now change the date relative to the date of each photo you selected. For example, if you selected two photos, the first being taken on Feb 13 and the second being taken on Feb 12, and then adjusted by 5 days, the photos would be changed to Feb 8 and Feb 7.